# Export["test.txt",111] doesn't export anything, generated a blank file

Tags: export

I am using Mathematica 11.2 windows version
I found that

```
Export["test.txt",111]
```

generated a blank txt file. However, `Export["test.dat",111]` is right. But the doc says

> Export["file.txt",expr] exports any expression to a text file.

Is it a bug?

PS. I just tried 11.2 linux version. `Export["test.txt",111]` has no such problem.

---

**update**

generally, "Text" option is corrupted on my Mathematica, for example

`Export["test.dat", 111, "Text"]`

also output blank file. But I have to use `Export["test.dat", ..., "Text", DOSTextFormat -> False]`, Does anyone encountered the same problem? However to solve it?

---

**update2**

Several hours passed, I finally figure it out, and the result is quite peculiar, and seems like a bug.

Things goes like this.

If you add

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"]
```

into your Mathematica's init file, then quit kernel, and run `Export[file,content,"Text"]`, you will find the file is blank.

But If you just run `` Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"] `` in your notebook, it doesn't affect `Export`.

Quite odd! Wait someone to confirm.

---

**update3**

also `` Needs["CCodeGenerator`"] `` has the same problem if you put it in your init file.

Comment: Works fine in Win10 V11.2

Comment: Hi, @Kuba. I am also on win10. I know this is ridiculous. But do you have any idea of figure out what is going on with my mathematica?

Comment: If `Export` is disabled, many of my function is not reliable. And I just took an hour to trace bug down to Export

Comment: @Kuba `Export["test.txt",111,"Table"]` is working. But `Export["test.txt",111]` is blank

Comment: Can't experiment atm and don't know out of my head. :/

Comment: Export["test.txt",111] works fine on Mac OS as well. Have you tried the obvious things... restarting the kernel, setting preferences back to default. Removing any customized "execute on launch" notebooks?

Comment: Hi, @bills. I figure out what is going wrong.See update. Can you have a test on Mac OS?

Comment: Hi, @Kuba. I made a update.

Comment: I find that it is unsafe to put things in `init.m` that *do things* rather than just create definitions. Certain things don't work properly during kernel initialization. It is unclear what gets evaluated when you load this package.  You can see if DeclarePackage can be used as a workaround in this case.

Comment: Hi, @Szabolcs. Thank you. I will take your advice. But do you mean there is always specially additional operation done when loading `init.m` file?